# Parsing a UITextDocumentProxy in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently developing a custom keyboard app and am having trouble parsing what the keyboard has outputted onto the text document proxy. How does one go about this? I feel like I'm losing my mind. Currently I'm looping:

```
for letter in (proxy.documentContextBeforeInput?.characters)!
```

However, this is only getting the text on the line the cursor is currently on, before the cursor, such that if my textDocumentProxy contains:

> Some text above
>
> Some text below (cursor position)

My loop only iterates throught the "Some text below" portion.

Is there any way to loop through the entirety of a UITextDocumentProxy? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

`documentContextBeforeInput`, as its name mentions, only returns the text before the input. To get the full text string, you should do something like:

```
let entireText = (proxy.documentContextBeforeInput ?? "") + (proxy.documentContextAfterInput ?? "")

if let chars = entireText.characters {
    for letter in chars {
        //DO something useful
    }
}
```